# What is the purpose of the "v0" signature scheme in the Stripe webhook API?

Tags: stripe-payments

The Stripe documentation on [signature verification](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-manually) says:

> Currently, the only valid signature scheme is `v1`. To aid with testing, Stripe sends an additional signature with a fake `v0` scheme, for test-mode events.
>
> ```
> Stripe-Signature: t=1492774577,
>     v1=5257a869e7ecebeda32affa62cdca3fa51cad7e77a0e56ff536d0ce8e108d8bd,
>     v0=6ffbb59b2300aae63f272406069a9788598b792a944a07aba816edb039989a39
> ```

In what way does the `v0` signature aid with testing? What might I use it for?

How is the `v0` signature generated? Is it just a random string, or is it some HMAC digest that can be verified, similar to the `v1` scheme?

Answer (score 0):

The `v0` scheme can be useful if you are building your own client to verify Stripe's webhook event signatures. It is intended for testing that your client ignores unknown scheme(s) (or, perhaps, at some point in the future, a deprecated scheme) in the `Stripe-Signature` header.

The `v0` digest does not use the signing secret generated for your endpoint; Stripe has not released the secret used to create it, so you cannot verify it.

Stripe's own [client libraries](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/test/stripe/webhook_test.rb#L56) include a test case around ignoring invalid schemes. For example, in the Ruby lib:

```
should "raise a SignatureVerificationError when there are no signatures with the expected scheme" do
  header = generate_header(scheme: "v0")
  e = assert_raises(Stripe::SignatureVerificationError) do
    Stripe::Webhook::Signature.verify_header(EVENT_PAYLOAD, header, "secret")
  end
  assert_match("No signatures found with expected scheme", e.message)
end
```